# How to avoid anonymox startup screen using selenium web driver in java?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm using two plugins within my selenium firefox profile in java. For one, setting the current version to avoid the startup screen worked perfectly fine but for anonymox, I can't seem to get it to work.

My code:

```
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffProfile.addExtension(new File("anonymox-2.5.2-fx.xpi"));
ffProfile.setPreference("anonymox.currentVersion", "2.5.2");
ffProfile.setPreference("anonymox.firstrun", false); 
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);
```

For some reason, the startup tab is still being displayed and my code doesn't run, since it (naturally) can't find any element it is looking for on the anonymox page, which is now the active tab.

How can I change my code that this will work?

I have tried the possibility of just closing tabs, but sometimes anonymox doesn't load fast enough and I end up closing the website tab instead.

```
String closeTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "w");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div")).sendKeys(closeTab);
```

Thus, I would prefer to avoid the startup tab altogether.